# Battery stops charging after 64% percent, HP Pavilion 14

Tags: battery

I am a noob to Linux. I just changed from Windows to Linux. How can I solve this battery issue?

I think battery seems good.

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Hewlett-Packard
  model:                Primary
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 15 Jun 2019 10:38:48 PM +0630 (112 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              18.1104 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         32.8944 Wh
    energy-full-design:  32.8944 Wh
    energy-rate:         11.4345 W
    voltage:             11.883 V
    time to empty:       1.6 hours
    percentage:          55%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-good-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1560614928  55.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1560614928  11.434  discharging
```

Comment: It seems like a hardware problem, not an OS one. Did you had a different read of charge in Windows?

Comment: It used to work fine in Windows

Comment: Use the command `upower -e`, which will prompt a line similar to this `/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`. Then run `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` and look for the `state` option.

Comment: Have you tried checking for bios updates or resetting the bios to defaults?

Comment: I answered a very similar question a while ago (similar or same machine), but you probably need to try and apply pressure to the charging cable to see if reconnects. In that other question, we established that there isnt an OS component that would prevent your machine from charging past a certain point. My guess is the place it stops charging is probably just a coincidence. HP's are notorious for bad charging ports. If you diagnose it as such, you will need to either replace the charger itself or the little cube it plugs into inside the machine. Let us know what you find.

Comment: @jwcooper In Windows you can set the machine to only charge up to a given percent. This is done to conserve battery life. Once set in Windows and dual booting into Linux I know no way of resetting percentage. I had to go back into Windows to reset percentage back to 100%. If I ever get around to kernel programming that would be a nifty little C program to write for Linux though.

Answer (score 0):

### Sometimes you just have to replug it

Here's my 1 week battery history:

[image: Power laptop battery.png]

When I first encountered the question above (not the day it was posted) I checked my own battery and was surprised it was only charged to 80% or so.

I unplugged it and let it drain to 33%.

I plugged it back in and suspended it overnight. The next day when I checked it was only 34%

I also noticed the power daemon was going nuts and consuming 20% to 25% of  CPUs:

[image: Power 20% of CPUs]

I rebooted and unplugged the charger and let battery drain to 6%. I plugged the charger back in (without suspending this time) and it fully recharged to 100%.

Since then it's been perfectly normal again.

---

### Original Answer

As I mentioned in comments, here is a Windows only answer for my laptop from:

- [Re: Plugged in, charging but won't pass 70%](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Plugged-in-charging-but-won-t-pass-70/td-p/4211919)

> The reason why your battery would stay upto 70% and not charge further
>   could be due to an option called "Desktop Mode" which might be
>   enabled. Desktop mode helps in disabling the battery to charge upto
>   100% to maximize the life of the battery. This option can also be
>   disabled. To disable this option:
>
> - Right-click the battery icon on the Windows notification area, and then click Dell Extended Battery life Options
> - The Battery Meter dialog box is displayed, Click the Desktop Mode tab
> - Select the option to disable this feature
> - Then, click OK

As I mentioned I have to go to Windows to change the battery charge limiter. I don't know how to do this in Linux. It would be a nifty little C program to write in the Linux Kernel some day.

Comment: This answer is really wrong in so many ways. 1st) The user doesnt have a dell, so they wont have the Dell power saving app. 2nd) Desktop mode in Windows applies to tablets, not laptops which op has. 3rd) I dont see any connection between this Windows utility and op's Linux question. They are completely unrelated. I'm not sure which version of Linux op is using, but if Ubuntu then there is no built in battery saving utility. The problem is most likely hardware related, but I didnt want to make that an answer without first receiving more feedback from op. Did you answer the wrong question?

Comment: @jwcooper 1) My point was to illustrate how you can have a Windows App to set battery charging threshold. Also how the App isn't available for Linux and you have to reboot into Windows. Yes different manufacturers will offer different apps. 2) "Desktop Mode" I was referring to is the name of the Dell mode, not a Windows function. I'm glad you brought these points up others may have thought the same thing. That said I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I've actually had two questions open at the same time and answered the wrong one by accident so I didn't know. Daemon issues definitely can consume battery though. I remember not long ago when the Avahi-daemon used to go crazy on my machine. Looking back at the original question, his battery seems healthy so I'm still going to say its a charger issue since he isnt really experiencing a fast drain, but an inability to charge to past a certain point. Curious to know what op figures out though.